# error | Invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int') -

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define OPERAZIONE_BINARIA ((2 ** bin))

int main()
{
    int n, NI, c;
    int fine, conta, bin;

    conta = 1;
    fine = 0;
    bin = 0;
    NI = 0;

    while (fine == 0) {
        if (fine == 0){
            printf("Inserisci un numero! ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if (n < 0 || n > 1) {
                printf("Numero non valido!\n");
                break;
            }
            else {
                NI = NI + int(n*OPERAZIONE_BINARIA);
                printf("Vuoi continuare a Inserire? (0(si)/1(no)\n)");
                scanf("%d", &c);
                bin = bin + 1;
                if (c == 0) {
                    fine = 0;
                }
                else {
                    fine = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Risultato: %d", NI);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

```
ERROR: Invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

C code building error

Ho visto altro su internet ma nulla! Non so come risolvere!
Magari c'è qualcuno più esperto di me. Grazie Mille!

Comment: Here are [all of the arithmetic operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Arithmetic_operators). It wasn't hard to find, and it doesn't include `**`

Comment: If you want that to mean exponentiation (as it does in Fortran for example), then there isn't an exponential operator, but `1 << bin` will give you two raised to the power of `bin`. You could get rid of the hideous macro, and just write `n << bin`.

Answer (score 0):

As @[MikeSeymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour) mentions in the comments, there is no exponent operator in c, there is a library function [`pow()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html) for the general case.

In your case, it seems that you want **2<sup>*bin*</sup>**, so this

```
#define OPERAZIONE_BINARIA (1 << (bin))
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define OPERAZIONE_BINARIA (n*((pow(2,bin))))

int main()
{
    int n, c;
    int NI;
    int fine, conta, bin;

    conta = 1;
    fine = 0;
    bin = 0;
    NI = 0;

    printf("Inseririre numeri da 0 a 1 partendo dal bit meno significativo!\n");
    while (fine == 0) {

        if (fine == 0){
            printf("Inserisci un numero! ");
            scanf("%d", &n);

            if (n < 0 || n > 1) {
                printf("Numero non valido!\n");
                break;
            }
            else {
                NI = NI + OPERAZIONE_BINARIA;
                printf("Vuoi continuare a Inserire? (0(si)/1(no)\n)");
                scanf("%d", &c);
                bin = bin + 1;
                if (c == 0) {
                    fine = 0;
                }
                else {
                    fine = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Risultato: %d", NI);
return 0;
}
```

I solved :D

Answer (score -1):

There is no such operator like `**` for integer types,
Variable  `bin` is declared as having type `int`.

```
int fine, conta, bin;
```

So this macro

```
#define OPERAZIONE_BINARIA ((2 ** bin))
```

is invalid.